# how to write this script in matlab

Tags: matlab, root, polynomial-math

I've just started learning Matlab(a few days ago) and I have the following homework that I just don't know how to code it:
Write a script that creates a graphic using the positions of the roots of the polynomial function: p(z)=z^n-1 in the complex plan for various values for n-natural number(nth roots of unity)

Comment: Break it up into pieces. First figure out how to find the roots of your polynomial for a specific value of `n`. Then figure out how to plot those roots. Then repeat for various values of `n`.

Answer (score 0):

so I am assuming the function you are using is `p(z) = (z^n) - 1` where `n` is some integer value.

you can the find the roots of this equation by simply plugging into the `roots` function. The array passed to `roots` are the coefficients of the input function.

**Example**

`f = 5x^2-2x-6 -> Coefficients are [5,-2,-6]`

To get roots enter roots([5,-2,-6]). This will find all points at which `x` will cause the function to be equal to 0.

so in your case you would enter `funcRoots = roots([1,zeros(1,n-1),-1]);`

You can then plot these values however you want, but a simple plot like `plot(funcRoots)` would likely suffice.

To do in a loop use the following. Mind you, if there are multiple roots that are the same, there may be some overlap so you may not be able to see certain values.

```
minN = 1;
maxN = 10;
nVals = minN:maxN;
figure; hold on;
colors = hsv(numel(nVals));
legendLabels = cell(1,numel(nVals));
iter = 1;
markers = {'x','o','s','+','d','^','v'};
for n = nVals
    funcRoots = roots([1,zeros(1,n-1),-1]);
    plot(real(funcRoots),imag(funcRoots),...
         markers{mod(iter,numel(markers))+1},...
         'Color',colors(iter,:),'MarkerSize',10,'LineWidth',2)
    legendLabels{iter} = [num2str(n),'-order'];
    iter = iter+1;
end
hold off;
xlabel('Real Value')
ylabel('Imaginary Value')
title('Unity Roots')
axis([-1,1,-1,1])
legend(legendLabels)
```